# conditional count throughout each row using r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count

I tried every solution but my problem is still there. I have a big df (20rows*400cols) - for each row I want to count how many columns have a value of more than 16.

The first col is factor and the rest of the columns are integers.

my df:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
abc   2    16   17    
def   4    2    4     
geh   50   60   73
```

desired output should be:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 count
abc   2    16   17    1
def   4    2    4     0
geh   50   60   73    3
```

I tried `df$morethan16 <- rowSums(df[,-1] > 16)`  but then I get `NA` in the `count` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may need `na.rm` to take care of `NA` elements as `>/</==` returns `NA` wherever there are `NA` elements

```
df$morethan16 <- rowSums(df[,-1] > 16, na.rm = TRUE)
```

If we still get `NA`, check the `class` of the columns.  The above code works only if the columns are `numeric`.  Convert to `numeric` class automatically with `type.convert` (based on the values of the column)

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

check the `str`ucture

```
str(df)
```

If it is still not `numeric`, some values in the column may be `character` elements that prevents it from conversion to `numeric`.  Force the columns to `numeric` with `as.numeric`.  If those are `factor` columns, do `as.character` first

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `crossprod`

```
df$count <- c(crossprod(rep(1, ncol(df[-1])), t(df[-1] > 16)))
```

which gives

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 count
1  abc    2   16   17     1
2  def    4    2    4     0
3  geh   50   60   73     3
```